# Anormal number of sims document in gensim

Tags: gensim

I'm actually injecting 77 document in a gensim mode by reading them from a database with a first script and i save the document on file system.

I then load an other doc to check the similarity with a vector

```
def read_corpus_bdd(cursor, tokens_only=False):
    for i, (url_id, url_label, contenu) in enumerate(cursor):
        tokens = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(contenu)
        if tokens_only:
            yield tokens
        else:
            # For training data, add tags
            # yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(tokens, dataLine[0])
            yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(tokens, [int(str(url_id))])
            print (int(str(url_id)))
targetContentCorpus = list(read_corpus_bdd(cursor))

# Param of trainer corpus
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=40, min_count=2, epochs=40)

# Build a vocabulary
model.build_vocab(targetContentCorpus)

###############################################################################

model.train(targetContentCorpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

##generate file model name for save
from datetime import date
pathModelSave=os.getenv("MODEL_BASE_SAVE") +'/projet_'+ str(projetId)
```

When i infer the vector :

```
inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(test_corpus[0])
sims = model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=len(model.docvecs))

len(sims) #output 335
```

So I don't understand where this 335 come from and also why

```
sims[0][0]
```

return other id than the tagged one in the yield section

Comment: `int(str(url_id))` is a bit odd as a document tag - what is `url_id` originally? Also, if using plain-int document tags, an array of doc-vectors large enough for your largest int will be allocated. So if you use (int) `354` as an id, the model will be allocated with 355 doc-vectors, for slots 0-354, even if you only provide it with 77 documents. With a dataset so small, you may just want to use string tags - the option of using raw ints is really there for datasets with tens-of-millions or more unique tags.

Comment: url_id is the id of an url in my database. i using it next to match some urls. Why is it odd ?. I was hoping using it easily to recover the right document after. What do you suggest for a tag in my context ?
it sims it's ok with : yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(tokens, [str(url_id)])
(i'd like to understand why an int extand the tag space if you don't mind)

Comment: Well, if `url_id` is already an integer, you could use it directly - so `int(str(url_id))` would be confused excess work. If it's a string, that `int(str(url_id))` would likely error or lose info. But it's hard to imagine a case where that construction makes sense, and so that's why I was wondering what `url_id` is, in terms of data type and typical values. It really doesn't matter what your `tag`s are, as long as they are distinct and natural for you to use to look-up related docs.

Comment: Early `Doc2Vec` implementations required string tags for all documents - but if your documents already had natural int IDs starting from `0`, storing all those strings, and the mapping to what int slot in the underlying array they referred-to, was a pretty big waste - for datasets with millions (or billions) of tags, that was a waste. So gensim `Doc2Vec` gives the option to just use raw ints, native to your data, to avoid storing the tag -> slot mapping. But without that mapping, all it knows is the highest int seen - and it needs an underlying array large enough for every int seen.

Comment: (If you were running with INFO level logging, and in a recent version of gensim, I'm pretty sure the situation you hit - a larger set of tags allocated than the count of docs presented – will generate a warning message.)